# Upper bound on the rational function of $z$ in terms of $|z|$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

> Show that:
>   $$\frac{|2z^2-5|}{|z^2+1||z^2+4|} \le \frac{2|z|^2+5}{(|z|^2-1)(|z|^2-4)}$$

I started by considering that for the above to hold $|2z^2-5|\le (2|z|^2+5)$, 
and $|z^2+1|\ge (|z|^2-1)$, also $|z^2+4|\ge (|z|^2-4)$.

I then tried to make use of the various triangle inequalities. for example, 
$|z^2-1|\ge (|z|^2-1)$ but am unsure of how to extend these ideas to the given inequalities. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is a MathJax tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference" Please make your question readable.

Comment: I reformatted the question; please check the formulas are as you  intended.

Answer (score 1):

The stated inequality is correct for $|z|>2$. It fails when $|z|$ is between $1$ and $2$, because then we have a negative number on the right.

Otherwise, it looks like you are done. Just use the property of division: if $A\le B$ and $C\ge D$, where $A,B,C,D$ are positive numbers, then 
$$\frac{A}{C} \le \frac{B}{D}$$

And if one of two inequalities $A\le B$ and $C\ge D$ is strict, than the resulting inequality is strict.

---

If you want to have an inequality that works for all $z$, put the expression on the right in absolute values: 
$$\frac{|2z^2-5|}{|z^2+1||z^2+4|} \le \frac{2|z|^2+5}{|(|z|^2-1) (|z|^2-4)|}$$
Then we can allow all $|z|$ except $|z|=1,2$  (or perhaps even those, if division by zero is interpreted as $+\infty$).

Comment: thanks,  but how do I show that the inequality holds and is strict. Also, what of this property of division? If say A=2, B=3, C=1, D=4...clearly (A/C)>(B/D)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help.

$| z^2+4 |  =  |z^2-(-4)| \geq |  |z^2| - |-4| |$
, by the reverse triangle inequality.

You can show that $|z^2| = |z|^2$ easily.